# JDeveloper error- Ear file Build

Tags: java, jsp, compiler-errors, ear, jdeveloper

I am new with JDeveloper(11g) and am trying to compile an ear to manually deploy to the webLogic server.

I work with mostly Java (through eclipse/ GWT) and some JSPs. The ear will mostly contain our JSP files.

**The problem:**

I get 2 types of errors:

1. cannot compile because:

   ```
   Error: cannot find class XXXX
   ```

now the file it is trying to reference should be on the server so I was hoping when i deploy it there it would fix the issue. But when i try to continue with EAR build i get:

2 . cannot build EAR because:

```
    One or more compilation errors prevented deployment from continuing.
    Deployment cancelled.
    ---- Deployment incomplete ----.
    Build failed. (oracle.adfdt.common.deploy.impl.AdfLibraryBuildDeployer)
```

Any ideas? is the ADF Library error because of the compilation problem? Therefore I cannot complete a build for an EAR if the file contains compilation errors? I pulled the old ear from the server and the file my current files cannot access is not in it, so i shouldnt need it in the EAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the JAR file with the missing class to your project properties under libraries and classpath.
This will allow JDeveloper to compile your project and then package it into an EAR.

Comment: Fixed! Actually the file was already selected in the Library but after removing it and adding again it worked great. Thank you so much! ..The JavaBeast rolls on...